# How to Change the Default Avatar - Mystery Person? [WordPress]

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

While bloggers may know about gravatar and have an account, there are other users who don’t have a personal gravatar, so when they post a comment on a blog, a mystery man takes over their gravatar.

I want to put my own Avatar there. I don't want to use Mystery Person and all. I have own Avtar placed in **[img]** folder in my theme directory. Named as **admin.jpg** I want to use this as default Avtar and want this to placed in **WordPress Dashboard->Settings->Discussion**.

**For this I have used hooks. I placed some code in my functions.php. Code is as below:**

```
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'ownavatar' );

function ownavatar ($avatar_defaults) {
$myavatar = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/admin.jpg';
$avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Navnish's Avtar";
return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

**Issue:**

When I went into [Discussion] sections. Its not displaying image there. Not even displaying that on comments.

**How its reverting is as below:**
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are also a few plugins that might help you get what you want: [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-new-default-avatar/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-new-default-avatar/) [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-new-default-avatar-emrikols-fork/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-new-default-avatar-emrikols-fork/) Please try it and let me know.

Comment: I want to do this work in codding. Without using plugins.

Comment: @NavnishBhardwaj i also try to add avatar using code but not working. i will try and let you know.

Comment: That would be great if you can give a try for me.. Thank you

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do this without using plugins?

Comment: @NavnishBhardwaj ok, i found the issue. Please upload your code on live server and its working fine. Default avatar not working on localhost.

Comment: These days plugins are main reasons for WordPress website hacks. Another thing is I am developing own theme. I want this as a part of theme.

Comment: @jalpa Thanks it worked on live server. Don't know why it caused issue with localhost.

Comment: @NavnishBhardwaj if answer is usfull for you please give me upvote :) thanks in advance.

Comment: @NavnishBhardwaj ok fine,  i did it :)